# What the relationship of web frameworks & others

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, pug, mean-stack

I've been mostly a LAMP stack dev but recently I wanted to get into the new stuff like MEAN stacks but all the stuff I'm running into are getting confusing, can someone help me clear it up?

So I've played around with a Node.js server with Express, Jade, and a mySQL DB. So from what I've read, Node operates the backend, Express does the front end rendering and Jade... does front end as well?

Also, for a MEAN stack. Angular does front end right? So what does Express do in that situation and does it need something like Jade?

All this new stuff is so much overload, I'm still reading up on docs about Amber, React, Meteor, Firebase, etc. Is there a site that documents these all together and how they fit together?

Answer (score 0):

Express doesn't do front end. Express is a framework which sits on top of Node.js and makes it easy for you to build websites. Node wasn't originally created to build websites, you see. You can consider Express to be a web framework for Node, just like Flask and Django are for Python. There are other web frameworks for Node too, like Sails and Koa. In the MEAN stack, Express generally does the routing and handles different routes in your application while Angular handles the frontend.

Also if you're just starting out with the MEAN stack, then you don't need things like Ember, React, Meteor, Firebase, etc. They're all different things for different purposes and my suggestion would be to not overdo yourself and take things one step at a time.

Comment: So Express handles the router.js file and Node.js handles the server.js file in my project?

Comment: No, Node.js handles both these files. Express is just a software or module which is written *using* Node to make web development easy. Just like PHP has frameworks like Laravel, CakePHP etc., Node has Express.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short description of what you are searching :

```
'M' for [MONGODB]
```

MongoDB is documented oriented database, its very easy to use and works very good with javascript. you insert JSON data and get JSON data in response from it.

```
'E' for [Express]
```

Express is Node.js framework with `http` verb (`GET, POST, PUT DELETE`) and middleware support. 
It supports routing with http and middlewares.

```
'A' for [Angularjs]
```

AngularJS is a front-end web framework that nicely hooks up with you nodesjs application. You can consume `RESTful` services from Backend data sources and build interactive single page applications(SPA) using angularjs.

```
'N' for [Node.js]
```

Node.js is a server-side javascript environent based on google's V8 engine. It is purely javascript environment. you can code in javascript and node takes care of it and run on web server.

Regarding `[Jade]` , it is a templating engine which compiles to `HTML` plus it is rendered from your server.

Comment: nice breakdown and summarized description (y)

Comment: What benefits does this have over the LAMP stack? I wrote an exercise today using the USDA food database API and Meteor, but it took soo long to setup. I had to make a template, use {{spacebars}} in the html, write the Template.helper, write the Template.event, write the Meteor.Method on the server side. Whereas if I did it in PHP, it would be in 1 file and much fewer lines. I see this with Node too where structure and behavior is separated, but I have to write into router.js each time I have a new page and manage a bunch of different files that took only 1-2 files in PHP before.

Comment: O, I thought M stood for Mongoose. So if I use a MEAN stack on my server, do I have to download additional packages to get the MongoDB working with Node, Express, or Angular? I've more often seen people using Mongoose for MongoDB when using Node.js.

Comment: Separating modules w.r.t behaviour (module design pattern) is one of the followed design pattern in javascript, it makes your code more readable and maintainable. MEAN has various benifits over LAMP, I cann't accommodate all the benifits here but some are, javascript on bothe client and server, asynchronous, non-blocking, highly scalable and various other. you can just google it around for benifits